# Mock Service without using constructor with Autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I want to edit this code to use mock for services. This code is working fine:

```
@Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;
    private Terminals terminal;

    @Autowired
    public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(Terminals terminal, RiskFilterService riskFilterService) {  
        this.terminal = terminal;
        this.riskFilterService = riskFilterService;
    }

    public void validateBinCountryCheckFilter(Terminals terminal) throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {

        List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(terminal.getId(), "BinCountryCheckFilter");
    }
}
```

JUnit test:

```
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest    {

    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {
        //Arrange
        RiskFilterService riskFilterService = Mockito.mock(RiskFilterService.class);
        Terminals terminal = Mockito.mock(Terminals.class);

        BDDMockito.given(
            riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(anyInt(), anyString()))
            .willReturn(riskFiltersList);

        int expectedInt = 11;
        String expectedString = "BinCountryCheckFilter";

        when(terminal.getId()).thenReturn(expectedInt);

        BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilterImpl = 
            new BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(terminal, riskFilterService);

        //Act
        binCountryCheckFilterImpl.validateBinCountryCheckFilter();

        //Assert
        then(riskFilterService)
          .should()
          .findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(expectedInt, expectedString);
    }    
}
```

This code is not working:

```
    @Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("riskFilterService")
    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

    public Response validateBinCountryCheckFilter(Merchants merchant, Contracts contract, Terminals terminal,
              PaymentTransaction message, HttpServletRequest request) throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {
               ...........

    }

}
```

For some reason `riskFilterService` in null when I run the JUnit test. Is there some way to implement the service wit the JUnit test properly?
In my case I don't want to call `terminal, riskFilterService` from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using field injection instead of constructor injection, you have to initialize the mocks by calling the following statement in your test case (ideally in the method marked as `@Before`)

```java
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```